# How to install Canon Printer MF217w on UBUNTU 16.6

Tags: software-installation

could someone give me an advise how to install canon printer MF217w on UBUNTU 16.4?,

From the application search your computer, I selected "Printers", selected +"Add", found network printer, and followed the instruction, and got the icon Canon-MF210-Series, 
during the process, I selected "print test page" – and it did not print,
and the printer doesn't work.

I have also downloaded the drivers from the usa.canon.com   website , 
but I do not know if I supposed to install it additionally, and how

I would appreciate any suggestion,
thank you,
Roma

Answer (score 2):

I work with this printer for last yaer.
To make it work on my Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, printer Canon MF217w was connected to my PC by network(wifi).

1) I downloads drivers from official site. Here is [link](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/laser/laserbase_mf_series/i-sensys_mf217w.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)).

2) Unpack archive. And go to unpacked folder. Here you could find `install.sh` file.

3) Run this file in console. By the way, use "bash", NOT "sh".

```
sudo bash install.sh
```

4) Than, you can add your printer in "System Settings"=>"Printers"=>"Add"=>"Network Printer"